# Java on Pi arm64 with JInput

Tags: java, jinput

I am still trying to get my Bluetooth controller working on my pi with Java. I found the project jinput from https://github.com/jinput/jinput and installed the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libjinput-java libjinput-java-doc libjinput-jni
```

When I run the test class it is working:

```
 sudo java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -cp /usr/share/java/jinput.jar:/user/share/java/jinpu-test.jar net.java.games.input.test.ControllerTextTest
```

but however, when I am using my project I compiled on my Windows 64Bit system, on the linux system I always get the error:

```
Failed to load library: no jinput-linux64 in java.library.path
```

Trying to run it the same way:

```
sudo java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -cp /usr/share/java/jinput.jar -jar /home/robot/MyFirstProgram.jar
```

I don't understand the difference, so I assume it is related maybe to the build.gradle

```
//Gradle file

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'idea'
    id "net.ossindex.audit" version "0.4.5-beta"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "4.0.3"
    id 'org.hidetake.ssh' version '2.10.1'
}

version = '2.6.0'

// Project definitions

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io" 
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    }
    maven {
        url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
    }
    maven {
        url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }

   
}

configurations {
    // configuration that holds jars to include in the jar
    extraLibs
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:latest.release")
    implementation("com.github.ev3dev-lang-java:ev3dev-lang-java:latest.release")
    //extraLibs group: "net.sf.bluecove", name:"bluecove", version:"latest.release"
    //extraLibs group: "net.sf.bluecove", name:"bluecove-gpl", version:"latest.release"
    implementation( group: "com.github.hypfvieh", name:"bluez-dbus-parent", version:"0.1.4")
    implementation( group: "com.github.hypfvieh", name: "bluez-dbus", version: "0.1.4")
    implementation( group: "net.java.jinput", name:"jinput", version: "2.0.9")
    extraLibs group: "br.com.criativasoft.opendevice.ext", name:"bluecove", version:"2.1.1-SNAPSHOT"
    extraLibs group: "br.com.criativasoft.opendevice.ext", name:"bluecove-gpl", version:"2.1.1-SNAPSHOT"
    extraLibs group: "br.com.criativasoft.opendevice.ext", name:"bluecove-gpl-arm", version:"2.1.1-SNAPSHOT"
    configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.extraLibs)
}

apply from: './config.gradle'

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

//Compile
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 11
    targetCompatibility = 11
}

//Jar
jar {
    baseName = "${rootProject.name}"
    manifest {
        from file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
    }
    
}

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest.from jar.manifest
    classifier = 'all'
    from {
        configurations.extraLibs.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    } {
        exclude "META-INF/*.SF"
        exclude "META-INF/*.DSA"
        exclude "META-INF/*.RSA"
    }
    with jar
}
fatJar.dependsOn shadowJar

apply from: './config.gradle'
apply from: './gradle/deploy.gradle'
```

Can someone please help me with that?

Thanks

Stephan

Edit:
Just to be clear. I only run my code on Linux, but use VSC on Windows to write and compile the jar file

Edit2:
I found this https://github.com/SteveSmith16384/jinputtest/blob/master/libs/libjinput-linux64.so which I copied in the required folder and is running without any issue. However, I still don't understand why I can run the local jar file, but not my compiled one.

Comment: *Failed to load library: no jinput-linux64 in java.library.path* Why would you be trying to use a library with 'linux64' in its name on Windows? A Windows library would contain a .dll

Comment: A build for Windows should produce jinput-dx8_64.dll for a 64 system. That file is required and the directory containing it would be the value (or part of the value) of `java.library.path`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Of course I am running the code on the arm64 Raspberry pi and not on my windows machine. The windows machine is just for compiling.

Comment: You can cross-compile to arm on that box?

Comment: I installed on linux the correct dependency libjinput-java and can also run the test jar file of this library. But I am not able to create my own jar file where I am referring to jinput by the gradle file

Comment: What is your command line on the Pi please?

Comment: sudo java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -cp /usr/share/java/jinput.jar -jar /home/robot/MyFirstRobot.jar same as with the test jar: sudo java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -cp /usr/share/java/jinput.jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237768/discussion-between-g00se-and-stephan).

Answer (score 0):

I created a link `jinput-linux64` to `/usr/lib/jni/libjinput`. Ugly, but it worked for me.